# array_keys not working in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to return an array containing the keys:

```
<?php
if(isset($values[0]->Content)):
$jarray= json_decode($values[0]->Content);
print_r(array_keys($jarray));
exit;
endif;
?>
```

Output of `$jarray`:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [_token] => QjyTAyDDUeadYvO0qj0gAZyK7OVyudSsY7Sq8Hhp
    [datefrom] => 2017-07-07
    [dateto] => 2017-07-31
    [Productivity] => test1
    [Productivityrating] => 2
    [Technical_Skills] => test2
    [Technical_Skillsrating] => 3
    [Work_Consistency] => test3
    [Work_Consistencyrating] => 4
    [Presentation_skills] => test4
    [Presentation_skillsrating] => 5
    [test] => test5
    [testrating] => 3
    [cycle_id] => 1
    [save] => proceed
)
```

I want to return an array containing the keys so i tried

```
array_keys($jarray)
```

but it gives an error like

> array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given (View:
>   my path)

Expected output:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>_token
    [1] => datefrom
    [2] =>_dateto
    [3] => Productivity
    [4] =>Productivityrating
    [5] => Work_Consistency
    [6] =>_Work_Consistencyrating

)etc
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it's not an array it's an object.

Comment: its because `$jarray` is an object

Comment: try `$jarray=  (array) $jarray;`, typecasting object to array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) returns a json string decoded into object in default (that's why get error). To get your json decoded into an array you should use it with second parameter equals `true` as following:

```
$jarray = json_decode($values[0]->Content, true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged as [`Laravel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel), I would suggest to go with Laravel's [`Key`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-keys) method that returns all of the collection's keys

```
$keys = $collection->keys();

$keys->all();

// ['prod-100', 'prod-200']
```

---

**Reference:** [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-keys)